# Lipschitzness of posterior mean of Gaussian process?

Tags: gaussian-process, posterior, kriging, rbf-kernel

Let $T$ be a compact set, and let $K \colon T \times T \to \mathbb{R}$ be a positive definite kernel.  Consider the canonical pseudo-distance
$$d_K(x,y) = \sqrt{K(x,x) + K(y,y) - 2 K(x,y)}.$$
Let $f$ be a function defined on a compact set $T$, and suppose that $f$ is $L$-Lipschitz with respect to $K$:
$$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq L d_K(x,y), \forall x, y\in T.$$
Let $X = (x_1, ..., x_n) \in T^n$, and let $\mu \colon T \to \mathbb{R}$ be the usual kriging estimator
$$\mu(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i K(x_i, x)$$
where $\alpha = K(X,X)^{-1} y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, where $K(X,X) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is the kernel matrix, $[K(X,X)]_{ij} = K(x_i, x_j)$, and $y_i = f(x_i)$.

**Question**: Is $\mu$ also Lipschitz with respect to $d_K$?  More specifically, is there a constant $c > 0$ (*independent of $X$*) so that
$$|\mu(x) - \mu(y)| \leq c L d_K(x,y), \forall x, y\in T.$$
[Feel free to assume as much regularity on $K$ (and $f$) as needed.  Importantly, the constant $c$ should not depend on $X$, but it can depend on $n$ the number of data points.]

**More context**: I'm actually interested in the case where $f$ is a sample from a mean-zero Gaussian process on $T$ with covariance kernel $K(x,y)$, in which case $\mu$ is the posterior mean given $\{f(x_1) = y_1, ..., f(x_n) = y_n\}$.  Under mild regularity assumptions on $K$ (e.g., see Adler and Taylor, Ch 1) we know that for some constant $L > 0$, $f$ will be $L$-Lipschitz on $T$ with probability say at least $1/2$.  I'm interested in whether $\mu$ will be $c L$-Lipschitz with probability say at least $1/2$.

I'm asking here, because I highly suspect this is known, given the amount of literature on Gaussian processes and approximation error for kriging.  However, I have not been able to find the answer in the literature.

---

**Some comments/thoughts/attempts:**

(1) Feel free to assume as much regularity on $K$ as needed.  For example, you can take $T = [a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $K(x, y) = \exp(-|x-y|^2/2)$.

(2) For my purposes, it would be sufficient to bound $\alpha = K(X,X)^{-1} y$ (e.g., in terms of $n$).  The naive bound $\|\alpha\| \leq \|K(X,X)^{-1}\| \|y\|$ is not good enough because $\|K(X,X)^{-1}\|$ could be very large if for example some data points are very close together (this is why the bound in Theorem 3.1 of [this paper](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2019/file/fe73f687e5bc5280214e0486b273a5f9-Paper.pdf) is not sufficient for my purposes).  On the other hand, it seems reasonable that $\|K(X,X)^{-1} y\|$ is not too large if $y$ are values coming from a Lipschitz function $f$; however I am not sure how to show this.

(3) Let $H$ be the RKHS of $K$ with inner product $(\cdot, \cdot)_K$.  If we knew that $f \in H$, then we know that $\|\mu\|_K \leq \|f\|_k$, and so $|\mu(x) - \mu(y)| \leq \|\mu\|_K d_K(x,y) \leq \|f\|_K d_K(x,y)$, i.e., $\mu$ is $\|f\|_K$-Lipschitz.  However, in almost all cases the sample path $f$ of a GP is in $H$ with probability 0.  So this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: As for the Lipschitz condition, you gave the answer (yes) in comment (3)! However for the important part *independent of $X$* I think that the answer is no. Think of the exponential kernel: the smoothness of the paths is that of Brownian paths. When the design $X$ becomes dense the kriging mean is very rough.

Comment: @Yves Thanks for the response!  As far as I see it, Comment (3) doesn't quite give the answer because $\|\mu\|_K = \alpha^T K(X,X) \alpha = y^T K(X, X)^{-1} y$, but it is not clear how to bound this quantity (independently of $X$).  For the exponential kernel $k(x,y) = \exp(-|x-y|)$, we don't expect the sample paths to be Lipschitz, so of course we don't expect the kriging mean to Lipschitz either.  However, for kernels which are sufficiently smooth, the sample paths will be Lipschitz whp and so it is reasonable to expect the kriging mean to be as well (with a similar Lipschitz constant).

Comment: Yes a path $f$ lies in the RKHS with probability zero but the Kriging mean $\mu$ is always in the RKHS. Again, the important part of the question is for me *independent of $X$* and maybe you should emphasize this in the question e.g. using italics?

Comment: Agreed, that is the important part.  I will put it in italics.

Comment: Can it be independent of $X$? Imagine $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = ... = x_n$. My line of attack would be to assume something on filling and separation distance of points in $X$ and use,  say, Teckentrup (2020, https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.00232 ) that bounds uniformly $|\mu - f|$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial answer to the question *with the context of Gaussian processes*.  I am still interested in an answer to the original question about kriging (no assumption about $f$ coming from a Gaussian process).  It is very possible I've made a mistake in the following.

We know $\mu$ lies in the RKHS of $K$, so $|\mu(x) - \mu(y)| \leq \|\mu\|_K d_K(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in T$ (see [Schaback](http://num.math.uni-goettingen.de/schaback/teaching/Appverf_II.pdf) pg 9).
Here, $\|\mu\|_K = \alpha^\top K(X,X) \alpha = y^\top K(X,X)^{-1} y = z^\top z$ and $z = K(X,X)^{-1/2} y$.

We know that $y$ is a sample from a mean-zero Gaussian with covariance matrix $K(X,X)$.  Hence, $z$ is a sample from a mean-zero Gaussian with covariance matrix $K(X,X)^{-1/2} K(X,X) K(X,X)^{-1/2} = I$.  Therefore, $z^T z$ is a sample from a chi-squared distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom, which has mean $n$.  So by Markov's inequality, $\|\mu\|_K \leq 2n$ with probability at least $1/2$.

We didn't make any regularity assumptions about $K$.  I'd imagine that if do make such assumptions then it should be possible to significantly improve this bound of $O(n)$-Lipschitzness (although I don't see how to do this).